# JDBC select query

Tags: ballerina

How can I `SELECT * FROM table` without specifying a record type and then iterate over the results (not loaded in memory, our tables are HUGE)?

What I need is to iterate row by row while converting each row to `JSON`.

I basically want to do something like this:

```
var selectRet  = testdb->select("SELECT * FROM some_table", ());
.
.
.
foreach row in tb { io:println(<json> row);}
```

After a week of studying `ballerina.io documentation, I am still unable to accomplish this without first specifying the exact ROW structure with a type row record { ..... }, which is very inconvenient when your table has 200 columns.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally conversion to json should not load whole table in to memory. But due to this [known issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/9619) server goes OOM during table to json conversion. The fix will be delivered in an upcoming release soon.

Is your use case iterating the table and converting each row to json? If that is the case once the above mentioned issue is fixed you should be able to do it as follows without the memory getting filled.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/mysql;

endpoint mysql:Client testDB {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    name: "testdb",
    username: "root",
    password: "123",
    poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 },
    dbOptions: { useSSL: false }
};


function main(string... args) {
    var selectRet = testDB->select("SELECT * FROM employee", ());

    table dt;
    match selectRet {
        table tableReturned => dt = tableReturned;
        error err => io:println("Select data from the table failed: "
                + err.message);
    }

    var ret = <json>dt;

    json jsonData;
    match ret {
        json j => jsonData = j;
        error e => io:println("Error occurred while converting the table to json" + e.message);
    }

    foreach j in jsonData {
        match j {
            string js => {
                io:println("string value: ", js);
            }
            json jx => {
                io:println("non-string value: ", jx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly ...trying to convert each row to json , do some transformations and output to a different database. Thank you for your example, it works well other then the OOM issue. Hoping to see it fixed soon. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can covert the table returned by the select query to JSON without converting the table to a record array. Have a look at the following sample. I tried it with the latest version of Ballerina which is 0.980.1. I've used the sample employees database here.

```
// This function returns an optional type 'error?' 
function performSelect() returns error? {
    endpoint mysql:Client testDB {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3306,
        name: "employees",
        username: "root",
        password: "root12345678",
        poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 },
        dbOptions: { useSSL: false, allowPublicKeyRetrieval:true, serverTimezone:"UTC" }
    };

    // If the select query results in an error, 
    // then the 'check' operator returns it to the caller of this function 
    table resultTable = check testDB->select("SELECT * FROM employees", ());

    // convert the table to a json object
    json resultJson = check <json>resultTable;
    io:println(resultJson);
    testDB.stop();

    // Return nil since there are no errors occurred
    return ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sameera, I am aware of this solution, but that takes up RAM. As far as I am aware, this converts the entire result at once and holds in memory. If you have 200GB tables, that's not good. Is there a solution where I can iterate ?